# How to limit number of characters of encoded string in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, encryption, encode

I'm sending an encoded value through URL, but I want to limit the number of characters after encryption using codeigniter's default [encrypt](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/encryption.html) library.

for eg:

```
echo $this->encrypt->encode("15532","key");
```

it returns like `Pl5Qi0Q2tekcvW7q/cBdiGgKC7VHUA4kNdzUbGZAOZ/gGHcWjm860pefAEki/e+OE1cGhi+5gcMPduXl3Xwg0g==`

How to reduce the length of this output. I know this is good, but i need this :(

It can be done by setting `$this->_mcrypt_exists = FALSE;`  by extending encrypt library.

Any other good way to achieve this?

Comment: try to keep them in sessions

Comment: I want to send this url to another server and return url also this type. i've updated the question. please check.

Comment: try to use `curl` and send data

Comment: You could change to an algorithm that creates shorter strings

Comment: @DamienPirsy, Thank you. if i didn't got any other way, i want to go for it. :)

Comment: keep in mind that if you create an encoded string and then cut it, the decoding won't work anymore: I believe the only solution is to create a shorter encoded string, and that is easily achieved with using a different algo

Comment: @DamienPirsy, yes thank you. now i set mycrypt encryption off for both decoding and encoding. so it works fine.

Comment: @MansoorkhanCherupuzha, Have you found the answer? I also need the answer.

Comment: No. as I mentioned in the question, It can be done by setting $this->_mcrypt_exists = FALSE; by extending encrypt library but it is not a recommended way.

Answer (score 1):

Setting `$_mcrypt_exists` to FALSE is a VERY, VERY, **VERY BAD** idea. Don't do that. It effectively means turning encryption off and using a basic encoding (but not encrypting) function instead.

CodeIgniter 2.2 was released because of that issue and it's Encrypt class now *requires* you to have MCrypt installed, it doesn't work without it.

On reducing the output: you simply can't do that safely.

Comment: Thank you, Yes I understand it was bad idea but I need to pass the URL to another website and they restrict the length.